# Why won't this 2D stroke be hidden in an 3D object?

Tags: rendering, mesh, grease-pencil, 2d

I've been trying to figure out why this mesh doesn't cover the grease pencil object in the final render (as shown in the figure below.)
[image]

[image]

Comment: There can be many reasons: you placed the GP object closer to the camera, you set it visible in front, you composited it in front, you messed with the shaders, .... If you want to know why it does it in your specific scene, I'd suggest uploading your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) so that we can check ourselves.

Comment: I understand!!! Thanks for answering me anyway! ;)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=sepa7KZX" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/sepa7KZX/)

Comment: can't reproduce the issue https://i.imgur.com/SepHqKM.png

Answer (score 0):

Please, read careful messages that Blender provides you:

[image]

So enable Z pass as Blender suggest you:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That really helps a lot!

Comment: @RyanHarrisArchibald consider marking this answer as correct then